# Multiple enum members same name

Tags: c, enums

I was browsing through some netfilter code.

I am not aware of any C rules which specify enum members with repeated names.

```
enum    ctattr_type { 
  CTA_UNSPEC, 
  CTA_TUPLE_ORIG, 
  CTA_TUPLE_REPLY, 
  CTA_STATUS, 
  CTA_PROTOINFO, 
  CTA_HELP, 
  CTA_NAT_SRC, 
  CTA_TIMEOUT, 
  CTA_MARK, 
  CTA_COUNTERS_ORIG, 
  CTA_COUNTERS_REPLY, 
  CTA_USE, 
  CTA_ID, 
  CTA_NAT_DST, 
  CTA_TUPLE_MASTER, 
  CTA_NAT_SEQ_ADJ_ORIG, 
  CTA_NAT_SEQ_ADJ_REPLY, 
  CTA_SECMARK, 
  CTA_ZONE, 
  CTA_SECCTX, 
  CTA_TIMESTAMP, 
  CTA_MARK_MASK, 
  CTA_LABELS, 
  CTA_LABELS_MASK, 
  __CTA_MAX, 
  CTA_UNSPEC, 
  CTA_TUPLE_ORIG, 
  CTA_TUPLE_REPLY, 
  CTA_STATUS, 
  CTA_PROTOINFO, 
  CTA_HELP, 
  CTA_NAT_SRC, 
  CTA_TIMEOUT, 
  CTA_MARK, 
  CTA_COUNTERS_ORIG, 
  CTA_COUNTERS_REPLY, 
  CTA_USE, 
  CTA_ID, 
  CTA_NAT_DST, 
  CTA_TUPLE_MASTER, 
  CTA_NAT_SEQ_ADJ_ORIG, 
  CTA_NAT_SEQ_ADJ_REPLY, 
  CTA_SECMARK, 
  CTA_ZONE, 
  CTA_SECCTX, 
  CTA_TIMESTAMP, 
  CTA_MARK_MASK, 
  CTA_LABELS, 
  CTA_LABELS_MASK, 
  __CTA_MAX, 
  CTA_UNSPEC, 
  CTA_TUPLE_ORIG, 
  CTA_TUPLE_REPLY, 
  CTA_STATUS, 
  CTA_PROTOINFO, 
  CTA_HELP, 
  CTA_NAT_SRC, 
  CTA_TIMEOUT, 
  CTA_MARK, 
  CTA_COUNTERS_ORIG, 
  CTA_COUNTERS_REPLY, 
  CTA_USE, 
  CTA_ID, 
  CTA_NAT_DST, 
  __CTA_MAX 
}
```

Here __CTA_MAX appears multiple times. Infact many other attribute enums get repeated defined.

When I printf the __CTA_MAX value it prints the first occurence enum value. `23`

So what is the use of the other __CTA_MAX values. What is the use of other attributes repeated.

Comment: What is the Linux or netfilter question? This seems like a plain C question...

Comment: That does not compile in C. Can you provide a link to the source code? (The definition looks different e.g. in https://github.com/threatstack/libnetfilter_conntrack/blob/master/include/libnetfilter_conntrack/linux_nfnetlink_conntrack.h)

Comment: @MartinR This is the link, http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/doxygen/netfilter/libmnl_2include_2linux_2netfilter_2nfnetlink__conntrack_8h.html

I thought it would be exactly like the original source. But according to your comment this wouldn't compile. So I will look at the original source.

Comment: My guess would be that this is a problem of Doxygen.

Comment: So ultimately, enum cannot have repeated names? It will not compile.

Comment: The enum is basically three times the same set of values where the last set is missing the values after `CTA_TUPLE_MASTER`. It's hard to know without seeing the header file, but I can imagine that the enum is defined three times in mutually exclusive `#if` settings and Martin R may be right in blaming Doygen for not handling (or being told to handle) the conditional compilation properly.

Comment: If the code compiles, `__CTA_MAX` is not a simple enumeration name; it must either be a macro or something built-in to some compiler that does something fancy.  The double-underscore prefix is reserved for the implementation to use, but I'd guess that is a macro of some sort.  For example: `#define PASTER(a, b)  a ## b` and 
`#define EVALUATOR(a, b)  PASTER(a, b)` and
`#define __CTA_MAX EVALUATOR(CTA_MAX_, __LINE__)` would yield names such as `CTA_MAX_23` as enumeration names where `__CTA_MAX` appears in the source.  Note that only one occurrence of `__CTA_MAX` would be valid on a single line.

Comment: Having said that, though, with all the other repeated enumeration constants, what you pasted isn't likely to be what's in the source code.  It would require absurd numbers of macros such as I showed before, and the enumeration values would be essentially unusable.  So, my previous hypothesis would work for `__CTA_MAX` alone (effectively, providing dummy names for enumeration constants that should not be used), but it would not work (sanely) with the other repeated names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C11 standard (taken from http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2):

> **6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers**
>   ...
>   **Footnotes:**
>   127) Thus, the identifiers of enumeration constants declared in the same scope shall all be distinct from each other and from other identifiers declared in ordinary declarators.

So using the same enumeration constant repeatedly in one
enumeration (or even using the same enumeration constant in two
different enumerations in the same scope) is not valid in C.

What you see is most probably an artefact created by Doxygen, and does not reflect the actual definition in the source code.

The definition in [linux_nfnetlink_conntrack.h](http://git.netfilter.org/libnetfilter_conntrack/tree/include/libnetfilter_conntrack/linux_nfnetlink_conntrack.h) from http://git.netfilter.org is just

```
enum ctattr_type {
    CTA_UNSPEC,
    CTA_TUPLE_ORIG,
    CTA_TUPLE_REPLY,
    CTA_STATUS,
    CTA_PROTOINFO,
    CTA_HELP,
    CTA_NAT_SRC,
#define CTA_NAT CTA_NAT_SRC /* backwards compatibility */
    CTA_TIMEOUT,
    CTA_MARK,
    CTA_COUNTERS_ORIG,
    CTA_COUNTERS_REPLY,
    CTA_USE,
    CTA_ID,
    CTA_NAT_DST,
    CTA_TUPLE_MASTER,
    CTA_SEQ_ADJ_ORIG,
    CTA_NAT_SEQ_ADJ_ORIG    = CTA_SEQ_ADJ_ORIG,
    CTA_SEQ_ADJ_REPLY,
    CTA_NAT_SEQ_ADJ_REPLY   = CTA_SEQ_ADJ_REPLY,
    CTA_SECMARK,        /* obsolete */
    CTA_ZONE,
    CTA_SECCTX,
    CTA_TIMESTAMP,
    CTA_MARK_MASK,
    CTA_LABELS,
    CTA_LABELS_MASK,
    __CTA_MAX
};
#define CTA_MAX (__CTA_MAX - 1)
```